# Run vim commands on errors?

Tags: vim, macvim

Ok so this question is vaguely related to one of my previous questions:

[I want Vim to be able to save and close similarly to Photoshop in regards to buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573942/i-want-vim-to-be-able-to-save-and-close-similarly-to-photoshop-in-regards-to-buf/13580809#comment18615191_13580809)

Basically the solution I found (or gets really close to what I want), is a plugin called BufOnly which basically closes all buffers that have not been modified. So when I have a lot of buffers open and I want to close, I just run this, and then just care of everything that I haven't already. It works well.

But I'm greedy. I want this to execute automatically when I need it to. Basically I would like it so that if I run qa, if qa runs into -->

```
E73: No write since list change (add ! to override)
```

Then I want to run

```
:BufOnly<CR>:bd <cr>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write a function with vim's try-catch mechanism. example:

```
 function! Funk()
    try
        execute "qa"
        let yes = 1
    catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E37/   
            execute "BufOnly"
            execute "bd"
    endtry
endfunction
```

this will catch the error `:E37` and do the command you want. I don't have that plugin installed, I therefore didn't test with BufOnly. I tested with "`h gg`", it shows the help page of `gg`

to call the command, type `:call Funk()`, of course you could create mapping for that function call.